# How to grep all lines starting with patterns from file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a nginx log file that I want to split in multiple files based on Ips. For instance, I have `ips1.txt` and `ips2.txt`. Each file has half of the number of unique ips of the log file. The nginx log file has the following format:

```
172.0.0.10 - [24/Jun/2018:11:00:00 +0000] url1 GET url2 HTTP/1.1 (200) 0.000 s 2356204 b url3 - - [HIT] - s - Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 10452.99.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.203 Safari/537.36 

172.0.0.11 - [24/Jun/2018:11:00:00 +0000] url1 GET url2 HTTP/1.1 (200) 0.000 s 307 b url3 - - [HIT] - s - Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 10452.99.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.203 Safari/537.36
```

So, what I am doing to get all lines that starts with the IP that is inside my pattern file is:

```
cat log.txt | grep -f ips1.txt > part1.txt
cat log.txt | grep -f ips2.txt > part2.txt
```

I know that the grep I'm doing is searching in the whole line and not just in the beggining. It's making the search slower and wasting more memory than it could be doing. I know if I have just one pattern to look for I could use `awk` (e.g. `awk '{if($1 == "172.0.0.10")print;}' log.txt`) but I don't know how to do this with a pattern file using grep.

So what I want is to waste less memory and make the search faster by looking just in the beginning of the line. My log file has many GBs and if it's possible I will save much time.

EDIT:

My ips*.txt files are being generated based on the number of threads I have. You can see bellow how my code is:

```
NUM_THREADS=8
export LC_ALL=C

unpigz -c log.gz | awk '{print $1;}' | LC_ALL=C sort -S 20% -u > all_ips.txt

lines_arq=$(wc -l all_ips.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)
lines_each_file=$(($lines_arq / $NUM_THREADS + 50))
split --lines=$lines_each_file all_ips.txt 2018/prefixo.

zgrep log.gz -Fwf 2018/prefixo.aa | pigz > file1.gz &
zgrep log.gz -Fwf 2018/prefixo.ab | pigz > file2.gz &
...
zgrep log.gz -Fwf 2018/prefixo.ah | pigz > file8.gz &

wait

unpigz -c file1.gz | pypy script.py -i - -o onOff -s 11:00:00 -m testing -y 2018 | pigz > onOff-file1.gz &
...
unpigz -c file8.gz | pypy script.py -i - -o onOff -s 11:00:00 -m testing -y 2018 | pigz > onOff-file8.gz &
```

Comment: `waste less memory and make the search faster` then you should start by dropping that useless use of `cat` :)

Comment: It was just an example. In fact the my log files has ~60GB each, compressed with gzip and I'll use unpigz -c  to decompress.

Comment: If you're aware of awk, and you want to make the search faster and more efficient, why are you bothering to use `grep` at all?  Use awk, scan the file once, split the lines into the appropriate file.

Comment: `cat log.txt | grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' ips1.txt) > part1.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use awk for the whole thing.  Read your fixed strings first, then split the log.  eg:

```
awk '{out[$1] = FILENAME ".out"} 
     END {while (getline < input) { print > out[$1] }}
' input=log.txt ips[12].txt
```

Reading the input file multiple times is going to kill your performance far more than the overhead of awk splitting the lines unnecessarily.

A brief explanation of the code follows.  The first (and only) command is to read the input and build an array of filenames.  The list all of the ips*.txt is given as input, so those lines are read into the array.  Ideally, these files are relatively small, so building this array won't take a lot of ram.  After the array is built, you enter the END clause where you read the log file (only once!) and write each line to the appropriate file.

It seems that you want to generate the ips*.txt dynamically, and that you just want to distribute the log.  In that case, try something like:

```
awk '! ($1 in out) {out[$1] = (idx++ %10) } 
    { outfile= "output." out[$1] ".txt"; print > outfile ; next} ' log.txt
```

This simply checks if you've already seen an ip: if you have already seen it then write it out to the same file you wrote the previous log.  If not, increment a counter (mod 10...pick your modulus depending on how many files you want) and write to that file, recording where you are writing the line.  Repeat for each line in the log.

The key here is to minimize the number of times you read the log.

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe the script could even be extended so that the files `ips1.txt` and `ips2.txt` are not necessary anymore. OP didn't told us so, but it seems like they would read the log at least twice. Once to generate the ip files and a second (or even third) time to split based on the ip files.

Comment: @socowi  I had assumed the ips*.txt files were known a priori.  If they are generated based on the values in the log, I think this becomes even simpler.  eg, if you want to split log lines base on /24 or /16, you can just generate the output file name dynamically.

Comment: *»Each file has half of the number of unique ips of the log file.«* sounded like something as `grep -P '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' | sort -u | awk 'NR%2==0' > ips1.txt` and `... | awk 'NR%2==1' > ips2.txt` was going on.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm trying to understand your code, but I couldn't yet. Like @Socowi said, I had to generate the ip file previously this way `unpigz -c log.gz | awk '{print $1;}' | LC_ALL=C sort -S 20% -u > all_ips.txt` After that I use `split` in all_ips.txt file.

Comment: I'll add an explanation in the answer.  If you just want to divide the ips statistically (eg, half in one file, half in another) instead of based on some criteria (eg, all ips with same first 3 octets in one file), then you can just alternate the output file as you go through the log.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'll split in more than 2 files. I just want to limit the number of files to the number of threads I have. I'll edit my question to explain better the context and how I'll use the output

Comment: If you want N files, you can put a counter on the outputfile name and increment mod N.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Is it possible to compress these output files?

Comment: To compress, use `{print | ("compress >" outfile)}` (or use whatever command you like to use for compression)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas to speed up your commands. Be sure to benchmark them. I was missing the data to benchmark them myself.

- Use `zgrep file` over `unpigz -c file | grep`
- Use a fast locale: `LC_ALL=C zgrep ...`
- Use fixed string search `-F` together with word regexes `-w`. Fixed string search should be a bit faster then the default basic regex search. For the fixed string case word regexes are the closest thing you can get to *»search only at the beginning of the line«*.
  `grep -Fwf ip...`.

or

- Compile your ip files into regexes and add `^` to the beginning to search only at the beginning of lines. Then use either `grep -E` or `grep -P "$regex"`/`pcregrep "$regex"`. Speed of `-E` and `-P` can differ quite a lot. Check both to see which one is faster.

```
regex="$(tr \\n \| < ips1.txt | sed 's/^/^(/;s/\./\\./g;s/$/)/')"
zgrep -E "$regex" yourfile > part1.txt
zgrep -Ev "$regex" yourfile > part2.txt
```

Comment: The second one gives me this error "Argument list too long". Zgrep with LC_ALL=C and `-Fwf` worked and it's fast. Now I'll compare with the other answer to see what is faster. Thanks